# Making a grid in a ListView ItemTemplate fill

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, grid, datatemplate

I have a ListView which has a data template based on a grid. The xaml is as follows:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SomeItemSource}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="281">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="3" Width="Auto"> 
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="70"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <!-- Grid content here -->
                <TextBlock Text="SomeTextbox" 
                           Margin="5,5,0,0"/>

                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" 
                         Margin="0,5,0,0"
                         Text="{Binding SomeProperty, Mode=TwoWay}"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                         Width="90"/>

                <TextBlock Text="AnotherText" 
                           Grid.Column="0" 
                           Grid.Row="1"
                           Margin="5,5,0,0"/>

                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"
                         Margin="0,5,0,0"
                         Text="{Binding AnotherProperty, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                         Width="300"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

What I want, is for the grid to fill (stretch over) the entire horizontal width of the parent ListView, however it currently wraps to the width of the sum of its contents. How can I achieve the behavior I want?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to set `ListViewItem.HorizontalContentAlignment` to `Stretch`. Try adding this into your `ListView` definition:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <ListView Name="Husam_Copy" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="181" Margin="60,86,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189"  >
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="{Binding Title}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Padding="0" Margin="0"  />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>


    </ListView>
```

Comment: Suggestion to also post what you changed in order to fix the problem.